# Is there a way to programatically/quickly assign all issues in the repo to a project?

Tags: github, github-api

It is possible to query `issues` through `Github` API. The JSON contains all info (`assignees`, `label`, `milestone`, ...) except the `project`. There is an endpoint to retrieve all `projects` for a repo but there is no reference between the issues and the project / project cards.

I am trying to consolidate two repos into one and hence I am also moving all issues from one repo to another. I was able to port everything except the issue project assignment. Is there a way to do this quickly? Currently it seems like I have to manually click on every single issue, assign to the project and then move the issue to the appropriate card in the project board.

Comment: https://github.com/gatewayapps/kamino might help, but not programmatically.